# Getting weird behavior from Oracle database running on a RDS

Tags: oracle

I created stored functionsin my ORACLE database 10 days ago. They were working fine at that time, but now they don't work anymore even though they are still visible in my ORACLE SQL developer. I had to recompile them in order to get them work. Why is this happening?.

EDIT: I am returning cursors in my stored functions. Maybe I am using them in the wrong way.

```
create or replace FUNCTION GETREQUESTBYEMPLOYEEID (ID_ IN REIMBREQUEST.EMPLOYEEID%TYPE)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  request_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN request_cursor FOR 
    SELECT * 
    FROM REIMBREQUEST
    WHERE REIMBREQUEST.EMPLOYEEID = ID_;
    RETURN request_cursor;
END GETREQUESTBYEMPLOYEEID;
```

Comment: they may have become invalidated due to changes you made to OTHER objects https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm#CNCPT1862

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment by @thatjeffsmith, changes made to an object, such as tables or views, will invalidate code objects which refer to whatever was changed. For instance, if you'd altered the REIMBREQUEST table I'd expect it would have invalidated this procedure. I don't know about other sites, but in our development databases at work we have a procedure which is run every minute which hunts down invalid code objects and recompiles them. If we didn't have something like this developers would spend inordinate amounts of time determining database dependencies and rebuilding code.